Can a countable group admit uncountably many non isomorphic homomorphic simple images?
Can there exist a countably infinite group $G$, and an uncountable family $\{\phi_i:G\rightarrow G_i\}_{i\in I}$ of surjective homomorphisms such that $G_i$ is simple for each $i$ and such that $G_i,G_j$ are non isomorphic for any distinct $i,j$?

@ArturoMagidin But the free product of all finite simple groups is not countable, no?

Since we can take $G$ to be the free group on countably infinitely many generators, I think you are asking whether there are uncountably many isomorphism classes of countable simple groups, and I believe the answer is yes.

I missed the "uncountable family". My construction only gives countably many quotients.

This wikipedia article appears to imply the answer to be affirmative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group. In it it is claimed there are continuum many tarski monster groups, and that each of them are simple and countable.

@Carla_ I would expect there to be an easier way to show this. Everyone knows aboutTarski Monsters, but the theory behind them is not remotely elementary.

@Amr: the free product of all finite simple groups is countable, but it doesn't produce uncountably many simple images (at least not in the obvious way).

I see this question now has four close votes. Could I suggest to these people that they are being pointlessly obstructive and disruptive? The post may get closed but will then probably be reopened a few days later. It is a pity that it is not possible to vote against closing.

Since we can take $G$ to be the free group $F_{\infty}$ on countably many generators, whose quotients consist of all countable groups, the question is equivalent to asking whether there are uncountably many isomorphism classes of countable simple groups.
If $S$ is any subset of the primes we can consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{S})$ obtained from $\mathbb{Q}$ by adjoining the square roots of the primes in $S$; these fields are pairwise non-isomorphic (they can be distinguished by when $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ has a square root), so there are uncountably many isomorphism classes of countable fields.
Next, if $F$ is any infinite field then $PSL_2(F)$ is simple, and countable if $F$ is. Apparently it's known that if $PSL_2(F) \cong PSL_2(F')$ then $F \cong F'$ with the single exception $F = \mathbb{F}_4, F' = \mathbb{F}_5$; see this MO question. I don't know how easy the proof is but that settles the question.
Edit: Here's a self-contained version of this argument. If $S$ is any subset of the odd primes consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_S)$ obtained from $\mathbb{Q}$ by adjoining the $p^{th}$ roots of unity for all $p \in S$. We'll show that the countable simple groups $G_S = PSL_2(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_S))$ are non-isomorphic by showing that they recover the set $S$. In fact $S$ is exactly the set of odd primes $p$ such that $G_S$ has an element of order $p$. In one direction, if $p \in S$ then $G_S$ contains the image of
$$\begin{bmatrix} \zeta_p & 0 \\ 0 & \zeta_p^{-1} \end{bmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_S))$$
which has order $p$ (since $p$ is odd). Conversely, if $G_S$ contains an element of order $p$, then this element lifts to a matrix $X \in SL_2(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_S))$ of order either $p$ or $2p$, since $X^p = \pm I$. So the eigenvalues of $X$ are $\pm \{ \zeta_p^k, \zeta_p^{-k} \}$ for some $1 \le k \le p-1$, which gives that
$$\text{tr}(X) = \pm \left( \zeta_p^k + \zeta_p^{-k} \right) \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_S).$$
It's not hard to show (using discriminants / ramification) that this occurs iff $p \in S$. So $G_S$ recovers $S$, as desired.
Edit #2: Here is an argument that avoids discriminants / ramification, but we do need to know that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is an extension of degree $\varphi(n)$, or equivalently that the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$ is irreducible. Since $\zeta_p^k + \zeta_p^{-k} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$, it suffices to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ is linearly disjoint from $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ whenever $\gcd(p, n) = 1$. But since $\gcd(p, n) = 1$ we can get $\zeta_{pn}$ from $\zeta_p$ and $\zeta_n$, so the compositum is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{pn})$ which has degree $\varphi(pn) = \varphi(p) \varphi(n)$, the product of the degrees of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. So they're linearly disjoint, meaning their intersection (wrt any embedding into a larger algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$) is $\mathbb{Q}$.

You got ahead of me with an easier argument, but I had just about convinced myself that the set $S$ could be recovered from your original proof using ${\rm PSL}(2,{\mathbb Q}{\sqrt{S}})$.

@Derek: it seems likely that there's a nice argument in this case too. Maybe you can distinguish them based on whether $PSL_2(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}))$ embeds, or some nice subgroup of this?

I won't try and write down the details now, but I was thinking the set of conjugates of unimodular upper triangular elements can be recognized by their centralizer being a divisible abelian group, and the set $S$ an be idenitfied by the conjugacy within that set of elements.
